# Endless notification: "Don't forget! You can invite [n] colleagues to create their own Careers 2.0 profiles."

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, user-interface, notifications

I get this notification on every page:

> Don't forget! You can invite [n] colleagues to create their own Careers 2.0 profiles.

Clicking the "x" dismisses it until the next page load. I can't forget because you won't let me!

Comment: I was just searching for this as it annoyed me as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the report Michael.  The fix is out as of a couple minutes ago.  Clicking the dismiss link should actually dismiss the reminder now. (Sorry Michael, I dismissed yours as a test.  I can add it back if you'd like :))

PROTIP FOR JASON:  Don't POST data when you meant to put it in a URL.